# How to theme an email template with vanilla forum?

Tags: email, themes, vanilla-forums

I wonder if anyone has ever themed an email template from vanilla's forums ?
I know how to theme the webpages but I can't find the documentation concerning email ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a topic that explain how to do this

http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/23562/tutorial-how-to-customize-your-emails

The solution is a little bit tricky, it consist on changing the translation in

`aplications/dashboard/locale/en-CA/definitions.php`

and add what you want to have in your email

**for exemple**:

```
$Definition['EmailConfirmEmail'] = 'here is some custom text :)';
```